# Get site URL based on GUID? (SharePoint)

Tags: c#, sharepoint

is there any code example out there that shows me how to get the url for a site if I know the guid?

Currently I have this code to get all sites within the site collection.

```
private void getSites()
{
    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
    for (int i = 0; i < collWebsite.Count; i++)
    {
        ddlParentSite.Items.Add(new ListItem(collWebsite[i].Title, collWebsite[i].ID.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just one other hint: You are massively leaking SPWebs here as collWebsite[i] creates new Webs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SPSite has a GUID constructor

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(guid)) {
    return site.Url;
}
```

And SPSite has a OpenWeb(GUID) method

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://somesite")) {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(guid)) {
        return web.Url;
    }
}
```